# How do I use a user environment variable in gradle.properites

Tags: properties, gradle, environment-variables

In a gradle task I can create a path like this:

```
System.env.FOLDER_PATH + '/subFolder'
```

but I would like to set this in my gradle.properties instead, so it would be something like

```
subFolderPath=${System.env.FOLDER_PATH}/subFolder
```

but I can't find any examples of this, is it even possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`gradle.properties` is a plain Java properties file. It can only contain literal key/value pairs.

Comment: Yes this is the case, I do hope however that this feature is added in the future, it would be very useful in keeping my code clean.

Comment: There aren't any plans for that. Whenever you need more than a properties file, use a build script (e.g. `build.gradle`) or init script (`init.gradle`).

Comment: I'm using a build.gradle and it has multiple projects and lots of tasks that have paths that build on each other, it would just be cleaner and easier to adjust the paths for different environments if the gradle.properties file could reference environment variables and other properties in the file. Something similar to this: [link](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-configuration/userguide/howto_basicfeatures.html#Variable%5FInterpolation)

Answer (score 0):

have you tried something like this?

```
subFolderPath=file("${System.env.FOLDER_PATH}/subFolder")
```

Comment: That didn't work, the problem is I haven't seen any examples of anything like this so I don't know if ${property} even works in gradle.properties.